# como puedo comparar dos fechas que son de tipo datetime pero que se compare todo excepto los milisegundos de dicha fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server, cast

Actualmente estoy haciendo una comparación de dos fechas en las cuales en ocasiones dichas fechas se diferencian por mili segundos debido a que eso es lo que se tarda en ir guardando cada una de las fechas y cuando quiero comparar deberían de coincidir pero como no coinciden los mili segundos pues algunas se quedan fuera de la consulta, asi que hice lo siguiente:

```
Cast([Fecha de Corte] as Date)=CAST(@fecha AS DATE)
```

Pero eso reduce a año,mes y día la fecha y yo quiero que compare también las horas, minutos y segundos de la fecha, salvo los milisegundos que suelen variar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No va a ser rápido, pero puedes convertir ambas fechas a `varchar`:

```
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(19),[Fecha de Corte],120) = CONVERT(varchar(19),@Fecha,120);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `datediff` y preguntar por la diferencia en segundos, si el valor es 0 son iguales, sino diferentes.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '2019/01/01 21:00:05', '2019/01/01 21:00:05') AS DIFERENCIA;
-- RESULTADO: 0
```